# English translation/interpretation of text given in photo.

Tags: translation-request, sanskrit

Yesterday I visited **Maa Mahakali**'s  temple in my city where I found this text written in *Sanskrit* and *Urdu*. Can anyone please help me translate this given text in English?
[image]

Comment: What is the name of the temple? Which city?

Comment: *Ma Mahakali* devi temple, City is *Petlad*.

Comment: Besides photo, can you provide Sanskrit text if it is clearly readable to you?

Comment: Its the shila lekha about the founder of temple etc

Comment: @RakeshJoshi , thanks for your help. Now atleast we know something about it. Can you please give complete interpretation of the Sanskrit or Urdu text? It would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Pandya , for now, all we have is this picture.  Thanks

Comment: It is hard to understand this text. Can you type the text in the picture and ask for interpretation on what it is written with some further details? Image only questions will be closed.